# Adding unique value to an attribute table starting at a known value

Tags: python, attribute-table, sequential

I have an attribute table with a unique values under polygon ID.  Last number is 679.  I am adding new 100 new attributes to this table and want to give these rows unique identifiers starting at 680. I do not was to change my old unique identifiers and I do not want to manually enter the new values.  What is the code to complete that?  I know there is on I have done it before.

Comment: Never mind I figured it outBase = 0
def CalcThis():
  global Base
  Base += 1
  return Base